# Run a method before any other method in a CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CakePHP we have `beforeFilter` and `afterFilter` to run methods before or after any controller methods (e.g. save log or check logged in etc.)

How can I do this in CodeIgniter?

Comment: just because you don't know how to do something doesn't mean it's impossible

Comment: I've always hailed CodeIgniter for its lovely set of documentation. Not your standard API, but Hooks are nicely described there.

Answer (score 12):

You'll want to make use of hooks in Codeigniter, that is where they have implemented your desired functionality of running code before certain points of the framework code.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

There are some built-in hooks that allow you to call a method or class at various points during the request:

```
pre_system
pre_controller
post_controller_constructor
post_controller
display_override
cache_override
post_system
```

So what you want is probably something like pre_system or pre_controller.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [_remap() function](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping). It allows you to redirect to your own function before calling the normal controller function. You can include your own _remap function in your controller like this (copied from the User Guide):

```
public function _remap($method)
{
    if ($method == 'some_method')
    {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->default_method();
    }
}
```

The second segment of the URI gets passed to the `_remap` function as a parameter (in the example as `$method`), and you can then redirect the process however you need.